# Converting force into displacement by using cumtrapz

Tags: matlab, math, octave

I need to convert a force array into a displacement array. I made this code but I'm having trouble with the displacement values that I get, because they are much higher than I expected.

```
clc;
clear;

log = dlmread('testThumb.csv');
time = log(:,1);
force = log(:,2)./1000;   #Converting from mN to N  


time = time(2:2904);           
force = force(2:2904);

force= detrend(force);

ace = force/0.0575;       #I get the acceleration by dividing the force between the mass

speed = cumtrapz(time,ace);           #Integration of the aceleration

position = cumtrapz(time,speed) * 1000;     #Integration of the speed and 
conversion of the speed from meters to millimeters

figure(1);

subplot(211);
plot(time,speed);                       #Speed in m/s, time in seconds
subplot(212);
plot(time,position);                    #Position in millimeters, time in seconds
```

The time between the samples is 0.05, the force is the force that a thumb generates with certain movements and the values are never higher than 20 Newtons.

These are the results that i got

[image: Results]

Can someone explain the values that I'm getting?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is to do with initial conditions when integrating. I don't have your data available, but consider this dummy data (I used trigonometric functions to make it easier to calculate the derivatives):

```
t = 0:0.05:10; % Time [s]
x = sin(2*pi*t); % Displacement [m]
xdot = 2*pi*cos(2*pi*t); % Speed [m/s]
xddot = -(2*pi)^2*sin(2*pi*t) % Acceleration [m/s^2]
```

If I now try to integrate the acceleration with `cumntrapz` without paying attention to the initial conditions and compare this with my speed profile, I get:

```
spd = cumtrapz(t,xddot);
plot(t,xdot,t,spd)
xlabel('Time [s]')
ylabel('Speed [m/s]')
grid on
legend('Speed','Integrated acceleration')
```

[image]

Notice the offset between the speed profile and the integrated acceleration? That is because of the initial conditions. The problem is compounded when you integrate one more time to get the displacement:

```
disp = cumtrapz(t,spd);
plot(t,x,t,disp)
xlabel('Time [s]')
ylabel('Displacement [m]')
grid on
legend('Displacement','x2 integrated acceleration')
```

[image]

So in answer to your question: figure out what the initial conditions are for your speed and displacement and adjust the integration result from `cumtrapz` accordingly to get sensible results.